# postgresql insert null value on query

Tags: php, postgresql

In my php code query, i got some error when i will place a null value 
into the table. The column names "number1","number2", and "number3" are integers and can have a null value.

if there is no null value, the query works

query is like this
 **insert into table(number1,number2,number3) values (1,2,3);**

but when I leave a blank value on the input form on the PHP,

for example I will not place value for column "number2", the query will look 
like this.

**insert into table(number1,number2,number3) values (1,,3);**

it says ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
SQL state: 42601

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

this query is likely to be the solution but is there any other way?
**insert into table(number1,number2,number3) values (1,null,3);**

because i got so many variables like that and am a bit lazy to place some conditions like when that variable returns a blank value then value="null"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You insert `NULL` value by typing NULL:

```
INSERT INTO table(number1,number2,number3) VALUES (1,NULL,3);
```

If you have a variable and when that variable is empty you want to insert a `NULL` value you can use `NULLIF` with the variable enclosed in single quotes to prepare for that (this is somewhat dirty solution as you have to treat the variable as an empty string and then convert it to integer):

```
INSERT INTO table(number1,number2,number3) VALUES (1,NULLIF('$var','')::integer,3);
```

Comment: is there any other solution than that? ^_^ because i got so many variables like that and i don't wan't to waste my time placing conditions on the variables whenever it returns a blank value, then assign that variable="null" .. By the way thanks for that :)

Comment: Ok, added another option.

Comment: tanx SIR... i place this on my code since the datatype is double precision

`INSERT INTO table(number1,number2,number3) VALUES (1,cast(NULLIF('$variable[$i]','') as double precision),3);`

Comment: $variable, be careful of SQL injection!

Comment: What should I do SIR to avoid injections? ^_^