# Python: Write values from a CSV-file into a postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, csv

I have made a python-script that takes an excel-file, converts it into a csv-file. My problem is that I have several null values in my csv that needs to be null, but as I try to insert it into the database, I get this error

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type date: "None"
LINE 1: ...', 'Some info here', 'And some more', '1995-09-06', 'None'
```

This is the code I written to convert excel-files into a CSV

```
def excel_to_csv():
    xlsx = pd.read_excel(excel_path + fileName + '.xlsx')
    xlsx.to_csv(csv_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False, na_rep=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)


    excel_to_csv()
```

And when I check the CSV-file, everything is formatted correctly, with values seperated by , and the null value is None, without quotation marks. It seems like the problem start when I try to read the CSV-file and then inserting it into the database. I use csv.reader for this

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute(
            "INSERT INTO databasetable (foo, foo2, foo3, foo4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);",
            row
        )
```

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Comment: Is "None" a legal date value for whatever database you are using?

Comment: According to your error message you are trying to set a date column to "None".

Comment: Yes, i know this, but it is supposed to be a null value. "None" in python is the same as null in a database according to the documentation. But it seems like the csv.reader is treating all the values of the csv as strings

Comment: The docs specify that all values will be string `No automatic data type conversion is performed unless the QUOTE_NONNUMERIC format option is specified (in which case unquoted fields are transformed into floats)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I see CSV reader is giving you lists of strings, so I'm editing my example accordingly

Postgres doesn't recognize the `"None"` (but your sql API apparently recognizes `None`.) You can try replacing all `"None"` with `None`. Something like:

```
for row in reader:
    clean_row = []
    for x in row:
        if x == 'None':
             clean_row.append(None)
        else:
             clean_row.append(x)
    cur.execute(
            "INSERT INTO databasetable (foo, foo2, foo3, foo4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);",
            clean_row
        )
```

Comment: This solved it for me, but I had to edit the code a little bit. It seems like csv.reader reads None as a string so if you edit the code this:

`for row in reader:
        clean_row = []
        for x in row:
            if x == 'None':
                clean_row.append(None)
            else:
                clean_row.append(x)`

This works! The database will now treat the value as a null value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that you need it to be `NULL` rather than `None`. See : [postgresql insert null value on query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162662).

Comment: It's still the same error, it seems like the csv.reader is treating both "NULL" and "None" as strings, not null values.