# How to insert with coalesce multiple columns into my log table

Tags: database, postgresql, function, triggers

I'm creating a log table from "users" and I don't want null values to be insert as empty. Btw this is de function i've try:

```
CREATE TABLE users_log(
    codigo_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha_operacion TIMESTAMP,
    llave TEXT,
    operacion TEXT,
    datos TEXT
)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION logger_users()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    CASE TG_OP 
    WHEN 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO users_log VALUES(DEFAULT,current_timestamp,
        NEW.id, 'Insert',CONCAT_WS(' ',COALESCE(NEW.*, 'NULL')));
    WHEN 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO users_log VALUES(DEFAULT,current_timestamp,
        OLD.id, 'Delete', CONCAT_WS(' ',COALESCE(OLD.*, 'NULL')));
    WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO users_log VALUES(DEFAULT,current_timestamp,
        OLD.id, 'Update', (COALESCE(OLD.*,'NULL'))|| '-->' || (COALESCE(NEW.*, 'NULL')));
    END CASE;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So if i have null values it insert like this:

(3,"Angelo Cuellar",AngelCrox,angelo99@gmail.com,Estudiante,70034265,trabajando,,,,,t)

and i want something like this:

(3,"Angelo Cuellar",AngelCrox,angelo99@gmail.com,Estudiante,70034265,trabajando,'null','null','null','null',t)

thanks for ur help

Comment: So what is the issue or issues your are having? I do see you are not using `concat_ws` in the `update` expression.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162662/postgresql-insert-null-value-on-query

Comment: The issue is it's registering like (,,,,,t) those empty comas, and i want it to write 'null' insted . I've removed the concat_ws btw. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: 1) I am not seeing the removal of `concat_ws`. 2) In `CONCAT_WS(' ',COALESCE(NEW.*, 'NULL')))` `NEW.*` is a record so the `coalesce` is going to be applied to the record as a whole not  the individual elements of the record. You would need to iterate over the record elements with `coalesce`.

Comment: An alternative would be something I blogged about here [Postgres and JSON](http://aklaver.org/wordpress/2021/12/07/postgres-and-json/). In that case `NULL` values would show up as `null` in the JSON.